# document object doesn't work properly in test with jest jsdom

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, jestjs, jsdom

I am using jest with jsdom to test my application.

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
const html = fs.readFileSync(
  path.resolve(__dirname, "../public/index.html"),
  "utf8"
);
let dom;
let doc;
let container;

describe("index.html", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    dom = new JSDOM(html);
    doc = dom.window.document;
    container = doc.body;
    dom.window.fetch = fetch;
    window.fetch = fetch;
  });

  it("renders elements", () => {
    new Form(container.querySelector("#app"));
  });

});
```

inside the `Form.js` file I use `document` to create and append element

```
class Form {
  parentElement: HTMLDivElement;
  localRootElement: HTMLFormElement;
  constructor(parent: HTMLElement) {
    this.parentElement = parent as HTMLDivElement;
    const formEl = document.createElement("form")! as HTMLFormElement;
    this.localRootElement = formEl;
    this.render()
  }

  private render = (): void => {
    this.parentElement.appendChild(this.localRootElement);
  };
```

and I got error:
`Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`

It seems that document comes from `jsdom` works ok because `this.parentElement` accurately has appendChild method attached to it.
However the form element created by `document` object can not be appended because it says it is not of type 'Node'.
I did console.log(document) that gave me `Document { location: [Getter/Setter] }`(No wonder why that didn't work)

My question is

Could I somehow assign jsdom.window.document to `document` object to do things like createElement properly?

Or is there a good alternative?

installed version

```
 "jest": "^27.5.1",
 "@testing-library/dom": "^8.11.3",
 "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
```